# How to detect if a point is inside whether a circle or polygon zone in Posgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL in a project that using maps I have a case that, requires storing `zones` and `warehouses` tables in the database. so I need to check a `warehouse point (long, lat)` is inside which zone?

`zones` table query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geodb.geozones
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    provider_id uuid NOT NULL,
    supervisor_id uuid NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    shape_type character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    coordinates json,
    status boolean NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
    circle circle,
    polygon polygon,
);
```

**Note:** I am using the native postgresql geometric types to store zone coordinates, I have 2 types of zones `(polygon, circle)` check the link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-geometric.html

**The bottom line:** I want to do something like so
check `myPoint` (long, lat) inside which `zone` in `zones` table
I tried these but it did not do the trick

```
select * from geozones 
where circle'(33.5097847983475,26.4893186229172),193595.565952562)' @> point '(33.914434873095,26.755303854071)'
```

you can find the Postgresql operators here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-geometry.html

Comment: Are you really using postgres 9.4? This version is "ancient" and reached EOL last year. As you tagged postgis in your question: why don't you use the postgis data types and its functions?

Comment: @JimJones I am using Postgres V10.17, the PostGIS has some issues with circles I am not talking in general but at least in my case so after a lot of researches and googling I decided to use the native geometric data types.

Comment: I see.. the documentation link you posted suggested you're using an older version. It is very surprising that the native postgres geometric types and functions have "less issues" than postgis. I just got curious :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

The circle is badly defined. You use `circle'((31.4018899807755,30.1252335173133),74041.8586826393)'`, which means a circle of 74 000 DEGREES around your long/lat ... so any coordinate on earth that you use will indeed be within this circle. --> use coordinates in meters.

The query should use your saved circles, not a constant one.

```
select * from geozones 
where circle @> point '(33.914434873095,26.755303854071)'
```

Comment: I am using this online tool to draw a circle and add a point inside of it check it https://www.mapdevelopers.com/draw-circle-tool.php
however I am using radius in **meters** and using coordinates in lat, long order

Comment: the tool your are using seems able to mix degrees and meters, but not PG's `circle`, it's all in the same unit

Comment: Also PG's circle center is `x;y`, meaning longitude first, then latitude

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this part ***but not PG's circle, it's all in the same unit***

Comment: either the X, the Y and the Radius are ALL in meters, or they are ALL in degrees

Comment: Ahaa gotcha but if you please me how can I figure out either the X, the Y, and the Radius are in the same units or not I did not even notice they are different?